# How to ignore the "avoid non-default constructors in fragments" error?

Tags: android

I got this error while trying to generate the signed APK. The thing is, my app is able to run and debug normally on my device. I don't know why when I try to generate APK, this error came out. How to ignore this error and generate the signed APK? I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 for Mac.

Comment: which error , can yo post the error ?

Comment: You should always leave fragments' counstructors empty, all initalization work should be done in onCreate() method.

Comment: Well, I'm more interested to ignore the error. How come my app can run normally without error when debug, when generating APK only this error message came out?

Comment: But if you're making your fragment parcelable, you are required to provide a FragmentName(Parcel in) {} constructor... so like, I dunno.  Even Android Studio makes this for you.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Found the solution. The easier way is to add these to the gradle:

```
 android {
          lintOptions {
              checkReleaseBuilds false
          }
      }
```

Or another way is to add `@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")`

Comment: You shouldn't have non-default constructor in fragment. You can add static method, like getInstance(your arguments...) and create new fragment from there and set those arguments to your fragment

Comment: Look at this example: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: Working Thank you :)

Comment: Its used for me THANKS A LOT

Comment: so if the engine light of your car is flashing, you also remove the bulb to solve it?

Answer (score 20):

turning off `lint` completely is not a decent solution if you still want to use the advantages of it. If anyone comes across this, I find turning off the specific error only a more elegant solution:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'ValidFragment'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is in the Fragment's contract: "*Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().*"

Answer (score 4):

For me only worked the combination of the two previous answers:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'ValidFragment'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

But remember, these a bad patch to avoid lint warnings/errors, the solution is to adapt the Fragment constructor to a public static Fragment newInstance(params) Fragment constructor.